# Как установить свои сообщения в woocommerce (error, notice, success)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть уведомления, выводящиеся по умолчанию.

Примеры:

- Корзина обновлена. (Корзина)
- Вы отложили “Товар” в свою корзину. (Страница товара)
- Товар удален. Отменить? (Страница товара, Архив).

Как можно изменить эти сообщения? В каких-то заменить текст, выводимый код.

Хочу сделать это без display:none, без замены строк.

Можно ли заменить именно в коде, в месте, где они задаются изначально?

Comment: Можно поправить файл перевода .po с помощью poedit, скомпилировать его в .mo и положить в ту же папку languages.

Comment: "Можно ли заменить именно в коде, в месте, где они задаются изначально?" Они задаются в плагине WooCommerce если вы их там удалите, то после обновления WooCommerce они снова вернутся. Поэтому либо меняйте как советует KAGG, либо убирайте/исправляйте хуками. Создайте в своей теме папку woocommerce и переопределяйте их там, если есть такая возможность. Все зависит от поставленной задачи.

Comment: Я о том и спрашиваю, как отключить я знаю, но на какие хуки вешать какое сообщение? Я не смог ничего найти по этому поводу именно.